# CORBA.COMM_FAILURE on calling an EJB method

Tags: java, websphere, rmi, corba

We run a WebSphere server with a few clients using different EJBs. One of the clients SOMETIMES fails on one specific method call (a KeepAlive method running every minute). We see the following exception:

```
...
Caused by: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA COMM_FAILURE 1398079696 Maybe; nested exception is: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: vmcid: SUN  minor code: 208 completed: Maybe
at com.sun.corba...
at...
...
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: vmcid: SUN  minor code: 208 completed: Maybe
at com.sun.corba... connectionAbort...
at...
...
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: vmcid: SUN  minor code: 215 completed: No
at com.sun.corba... transportReadTimeoutExceeded...
at...
...
```

What we do know is:

- This client application is the only one failing on this exception, and it uses an EJB that nobody else is using.
- The problem appears to be some kind of timeout, but it happens very quickly and we haven't found a possible configuration to change.
- In the WebSphere console we see that the response time of this specific EJB is about 360 millisec which is about 10 times more than other EJBs (but still OK? if that's the problem what might cause this - the WAS code?)

  Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at the FFDC logs and others to see what else is available in the logs

Try the suggestion here to see if setting that TCP Read timeout parameter to a higher value helps you.

http://kb.microfocus.com/display/4/kb/article.aspx?aid=26714

Keep this one for your reference:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/idl/jidlExceptions.html#minorcodemeanings

I am surprised that 215 does not appear in this doc. Minor code 208 does appear here.

HTH

Manglu

Comment: ok, i couldnt manage to recreate the bug in development env by changing these parameters, but i might try that as a solution.

Comment: Thanks! For posterity, here are versions of your useful reference link in newer versions of the java documentation (to prevent dead links, etc.): [Meanings of CORBA minor codes, Java SE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/idl/jidlExceptions.html#minorcodemeanings) -- [Meanings of CORBA minor codes, Java SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/idl/jidlExceptions.html#minorcodemeanings)